# Angular & PrimeNG: Not getting the CSS to work

Tags: angular, primeng

I am starting with PrimeNG but I do not get the cool styles.
But I do not see errors of ng serve or in the browsers log.

The components (I have a calendar and 3 buttons) appear but the look dull.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/calendar';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, CalendarModule, ButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/button';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',

  styleUrls: [
  "../../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "../../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "../../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"],
  template: `

<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" [disabledDays]="[0,6]" showButtonBar="true"></p-calendar>
<p>
<button pButton type="button" label="Click1" ></button>
<p>
<p-button label="Click2" ></p-button>
<p>
<button pButton type="button" label="Success" class="ui-button-rounded ui-button-success"></button>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ngtest';

    value : Date;
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: See the Angular CLI Integration section at the bottom of this page: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

Comment: I read that but I did not know there is some entry in angular.json about that. I thought syleUrls should be fine too. My fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the node modules of primeng css from the component that may not be possible

Try to add the node modules from the angular.json file in the styles array like below

```
"style":[
"./node_modulesnode_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css"

// Like this add all the css modules links here then try
],
```